# Exception for incorrect format in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

Im trying to test if the format send through the request url is json or not?

so in link_to I sent the format like this

```
<%= link_to "Embed", {:controller=>'api/oembed' ,:action => 'show',:url => catalog_url, format: 'xml'} %>
```

In the relevant controller I catch the param and raise the exception like this

```
       format_request = params[:format]
        if format_request != "json"
         raise DRI::Exceptions::NotImplemented   
        end
```

but the exception wont display instead the server simply ran into internal error but if I changed the param inside the controller then exception displayed so if the url is like this

<%= link_to "Embed", {:controller=>'api/oembed' ,:action => 'show',:url => catalog_url, format: 'json'} %>

```
       format_request = "xml"
        if format_request != "json"
         raise DRI::Exceptions::NotImplemented   
        end
```

why 501 exception does not triggered if I send the format as xml in url? Im doing it for the testing purpose that in case if someone send the request with wrong format 501 expetion show up

Comment: Use request.format instead of params[:format] which is only present if you explicitly pass that parameter. Its also a string inquirer instance so you can do request.format.xml? Which is much more rubyeske then comparing to a string - and use unless instead of !=.

Comment: But your really reinventing the wheel here to. Rails has MimeResponds which already implements this functionality.

Comment: I tried it but still the same it is not displaying the exception :(

Comment: since you don't actually have a reproducable example here I have no idea what you exactly messed up. I can just point the obvious like don't reinvent the wheel. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html and use rescue_from of you want to handle the exception.

Comment: I am using respond too as well but its one of requirement of an API that Im implementing that in case user send url with xml format it display the excpetion that its not implemented

Comment: Yeah. If you use MimeResponds it will raise an error if the controller doesn't handle the request format. Thus reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You should include the server error you receive in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ActionController::MimeResponds`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html) instead of badly reinventing the wheel:

```
# or whatever your base controller class is
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  # MimeResponds is not included in ActionController::API
  include ActionController::MimeResponds
  # Defining this in your parent class avoids repeating the same error handling code 
  rescue_from ActionController::UnknownFormat do
    raise DRI::Exceptions::NotImplemented # do you really need to add another layer of complexity?
  end
end

module Api
  class OembedController < ApplicationController
    def oembed
      respond_to :json
    end
  end
end
```

If you don't use `respond_to` Rails will implicitly assume that the controller responds to all response formats. But if you explicitly list the formats you respond to with a list of symbols (or the more common block syntax) Rails will raise `ActionController::UnknownFormat` if the request format is not listed. You can rescue exceptions with `rescue_from` which lets you use inheritance instead of repeating yourself with the same error handling.

Answer (score 0):

As @max mentions, sending the `format: 'xml'` is unnecessary because Rails already knows the format of the request.

```
<%= link_to "Embed", {:controller=>'api/oembed' ,:action => 'show',:url => catalog_url } %>
```

In the controller:

```rb
def oembed
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { # do the thing you want }
    format.any(:xml, :html) { # render your DRI::Exceptions::NotImplemented }
  end
end
```

Or if you want more control you could throw to a custom action:

```rb
def oembed
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { # do the thing you want }
    format.any(:xml, :html) { render not_implemented }
  end
end

def not_implemented
  # just suggestions here
  flash[:notice] = 'No support for non-JSON requests at this time'
  redirect_to return_path
  # or if you really want to throw an error
  raise DRI::Exceptions::NotImplemented
end
```

**If you really want to reinvent the wheel** (it's your wheel, reinvent if you want to):

I'd rename `format` to something else, it's probably reserved and might give you problems

```
<%= link_to "Embed", {:controller=>'api/oembed' ,:action => 'show',:url => catalog_url, custom_format: 'xml'} %>
```

Then, in your controller, you need to explicitly allow this parameter:

```rb
def oembed
  raise DRI::Exceptions::NotImplemented unless format_params[:custom_format] == 'json'
end

private

def format_params
  params.permit(:custom_format)
end
```

Comment: You're on the right track but a better solution here is really to not respond to the types you don't support and catch the `ActionController::UnknownFormat` exception as that is DRY and will bail early thus preventing the controller action from running. Also yes - the `format` parameter is reserved - for specifying the request format. It takes precedence over the request headers.

Comment: I agree with you, @max, I'd just say that your solution is a few levels deeper (and more correct), but might feel too much like the deep end for the OP, it almost does for me and I've got 5 years of Ruby under my belt.

Comment: Deep end? This stuff is covered by the guides and is pretty fundamental rails knowledge. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rendering-xml-and-json-data

Comment: Deep end from the sense of "MVC"-level vs. the Inherited level (Application, ApplicationRecord, ApplicationController)